# Displaying Images in ListView for React Native

Tags: image, listview, react-native

I have two presentational components. The first, called `Category` simply renders a React Native `ListView` component after doing a bit of set-up work.

The second component, `Book`, simply displays the data as text, with an image that should be fetched through the network.

Unfortunately, the `Image` doesn't seem to be displaying at all. Can someone help me get the image to display? Below, please find the `Category` and `Book` component definition, as well as a sample of the props being past to `Book`.

### Category.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListView, Text } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { camelizeKeys } from 'humps';

import Book from './Book';

const Category = ({ category }) => {
  let element;

  if (!_.isEmpty(category)) { // if data is available
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    const camelCasedBooks = camelizeKeys(category.results.books);
    const data = ds.cloneWithRows(camelCasedBooks);

    element = (
      <ListView
        dataSource={data}
        enableEmptySections
        renderRow={(book) => <Book {...book} />}
      />
    );
  } else { // if data is not available
    element = (
      <Text>Loading</Text>
    );
  }

  return element;
};

Category.propTypes = {
  category: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default Category;
```

### Book.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Book = ({ author, bookImage, description, title }) =>
  <View>
    <Text>
      {author}
    </Text>
    <Text>
      {bookImage}
    </Text>
    <Text>
      {description}
    </Text>
    <Text>
      {title}
    </Text>
    <Image source={{ uri: bookImage }} />
  </View>;

Book.propTypes = {
  author: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  bookImage: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Book;
```

### Sample Book Props

```
{
 author: "Vi Keeland",
 bookImage: "https://s1.nyt.com/du/books/images/9781942215462.jpg",
 description: "Reese dismisses a chance encounter with a smug stranger, until he turns out to be her new boss.",
 title: "BOSSMAN"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using images that come from a remote location (such as your `bookImage` you need to set an explicit `width` and `height` on the Image's `style`. This is due to the fact that there is not automatic way for react-native to know how big the images is going to be.

Check the [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) documentation for strategies on calculating the Image's size before being rendered. In my experience however simply setting the `width` and `height` explicitely is enough most of the times.

Comment: Thomas - thank you. That's exactly right. I found the documentation as you mentioned in the docs, but it was very subtle. I would have missed it had I not been looking for it already.